# ffmpeg why isn't metadata being printed

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to capture real time meta data related to the volume of my audio stream when encoding it into a flac file.  Ultimately I want to embed all this is a nodejs based web application.  I asked a question a while back using the showvolume filter and got all that working with streaming video, running ffmpeg as a subprocess.  I want to repeat this with a text based output such as I believe you can get with the -astats filter.

Here is the command I tried:-

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostats -f alsa -acodec pcm_s16le -ac:0 2 -ar 480000 -i hw:CARD=Microphone -af astats=metadata=1:length=1:reset=1 -af ametadata=mode=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_level_dB:file=- -acodec flac test.flac 2>log.txt
```

I expected to see stats on the standard output, but saw nothing.  The flac file was fine and the log file didn't show any problems.

I thought I understood how astats worked;  as configured it should add metadata to the audio stream of 1 second samples of the audio.  The second watches the metadata in the stream and when the Peak Level dB is seen it should output it to the file called standard output.

Obviously I have misunderstood something and haven't really found any examples to check against.  Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple filters should be applied within the same `-af` separated by a comma. Additionally, by default, ametadata will wait for its buffer to fill before it writes out the data. Add `direct=1` to force realtime output. But this option is only available in current git builds.

Use
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostats -f alsa -acodec pcm_s16le -ac:0 2 -ar 480000 -i hw:CARD=Microphone -af astats=metadata=1:length=1:reset=1,ametadata=mode=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_level_dB:file=-:direct=1 -acodec flac test.flac 2>log.txt`

Comment: I dont have acccess to the latest version, bit I found this following worked well enough `ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostats -f alsa -acodec pcm_s16le -ac:0 2 -ar 480000 -i hw:CARD=Microphone -filter_complex asplit=2[main][vols],[vols]ebur128=peak=true[vol] -map [main] -acodec flac recordings/out.flac -map [vol] -f null - `

Comment: For latest version, get a git master build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/